# Switching data between TableViewControllers and ViewControllers / Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am developing a learn/tutorial app and it has 3 main view controllers:

1. TableViewController: You can select a certain type of lesson.
2. SecondTableViewController: You can select a lesson of the previous selected lesson-type.
3. ContentViewController: This is a single-page-application with content (textViews) which gets filled depending which lessonType and lesson you chose. This view stays always the same, just the content/words are different. It also has a "next"-button which fills the textViews with the content from the next lesson.

These controllers are embed in a navigationController. So i discard the ContentViewController by clicking "back" or by finishing all lessons.

My goals: 
I want to have "checkmarks" in the cells from the secondTableViewController if i completed one lesson (with clicking the next button).
I also want to have the information how many lessons where completed (for example: 5/13) in the cells from the firstTableViewController which lets you choose the type of lessons.

My Questions:
- Where should i save the progress -the checkmarks and the information how many i have completed? (in a class? or just in arrays defined in these viewcontrollers?)
- How do i get the information passed between the ViewControllers? (prepareForSegue + delegate ?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is too broad.  [You're trying to solve too many problems at once](http://importblogkit.com/2015/05/how-do-you-eat-an-elephant/).  Break your problems down into smaller, separate, easy to solve problems and solve these problems one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a Model Class and make it Singular. Then you let that handle and store your data and call it from the other controllers to get/provide new data.